# embed information in NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

I am working with HTML which has some extra data stored in attributes of tags. In order to display the text, I am using `DTCoreText` to convert HTML to `NSAttributedString`. When user interacts with a piece of text, I would like to go back and find the data corresponding to this text. My original thought is to modify the HTML to `NSAttributedString` conversion and add extra information as attributes, which may not be an easy task. I would like to ask anyone with experience in `NSAttributedString`, `DTCoreText`, or `DTRichTextEditor`, is it feasible?
Is it possible to store non-standard attribute to `NSAttributedString` as attachment maybe?f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [NSAttributedString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> An attributed string identifies attributes by name, using an
>   NSDictionary object to store a value under the given name. **You can
>   assign any attribute name/value pair you wish to a range of
>   characters—it is up to your application to interpret custom attributes**
>   (see Attributed String Programming Guide). If you are using attributed
>   strings with the Core Text framework, you can also use the attribute
>   keys defined by that framework. In iOS, standard attribute keys are
>   described in the “Constants” section of NSAttributedString UIKit
>   Additions Reference. In OS X, standard attribute keys are described in
>   the “Constants” section of NSAttributedString Application Kit
>   Additions Reference.

You can store arbitrary attributes in an attributed string.  Thus you should be able to do a 1 to 1 matchup between your HTML and attributed string text by manually adding a unique identifier to both the original HTML and the attributed string that it produces.

If a such unique identifier does not already exist in your HTML this may mean manually pre-processing your HTML to break it down into the chunks that will then be converted to individual attributed strings in order to add the unique identifier - which will change that HTML so it is no longer truly the original text!